# Excel is automatically rounding large numbers - trying to solve this with python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

When I type big numbers into excel e.g. 12345678912345678 excel automatically round it into 12345678912340000
I'm trying to solve this problem with python but it doesn't work
I'm trying all the solutions from web so i really need help.
I cant add a single quote (') before entering large numbers because they are generating into an excel automatically from the other program.

python code:

```
import openpyxl
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

## Ustaw precyzję liczb Decimal ##
getcontext().prec = 50

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()  # Ukryj główne okno Tkinter
file_path = askopenfilename(title="Wybierz plik Excela", filetypes=[("Pliki Excela", "*.xlsx")])

if file_path:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
    arkusz = wb.active

    for wiersz in arkusz.iter_rows():
        for komorka in wiersz:
            if isinstance(komorka.value, (float, int)):
                komorka.value = Decimal(str(komorka.value))

    # Zapisz zmiany do pliku Excela
    wb.save(file_path)
    print("Operacja zakończona sukcesem.")
else:
    print("Nie wybrano pliku Excela.")
```

Comment: Excel automatically stores very large numbers with decimal exponential notation, this isn't something that can be solved with Python. You'll need to go to the source of the data to change the format.

Comment: How exactly is the content being generated?

Comment: As @David Culbreth states, large numbers in Excel are automatically changed to exponential notation (EN). If it is 15 numbers or less Excel may convert it to EN for display purposes but the whole number is saved in Excel. Greater than 15 numbers and it is **also** saved by Excel using EN so '12345678912345678' would be saved as '1.23456789123456E+16' which means the last two numbers, 7 & 8 are lost. Therefore the number can only be read as '12345678912345600'. There is nothing Python can do to re-create those lost two numbers it can only read from the cell the value that it contains.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i dont know how but it was exported from the another program and i cant do antyhing with that

Comment: @DavidCulbreth  So do you have any idea how can i make this number visible? the missing number is the item code and i need it to be fully visible

Comment: Without modifying the export/import process, you will **not** be able to recover those extra digits. At the time values are put into Excel, they are being considered as **numbers**. Since Excel's documented precision is 15 digits, extra digits are removed and there is no way to recover them. You will need to alter the export/import process so as to ensure those values are imported as **text** and not as numbers.

Comment: Excel has limited precision. This makes it unsuitable for scientific work. The **only** way to avoid this is to use strings.

Comment: ok, thanks you all, i can delete first 5 digits from this item code but still it isn't visible

Comment: i have resolved this problem using powershell, powershell delete some digits and they are displayed properly, thank you all